# VS code auto-format messes up line breaks and pointer declarations

Tags: visual-studio-code

1. I have a C statement that I have put over 2 lines to make it readable. When I save the file, the line is auto-formatted to one line - I do not want his.
2. I declare a C pointer like this:  `int* myptr;` . When I save this, it gets changed to `int *myptr`. Eg the asterisk is moved - I do not want this.

How do I stop the auto-formatter from doing the above 2 actions? The formatter is good for other things though.

Comment: Are you using the newest version of VS code? Do you have Code Formatting extension like Prettier?

Comment: version 1.52.1   I do not have Prettier extension

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Go to Preferences->Settings->Extensions->C_Cpp:Formatting – set to Disabled